# What is the best way to save sparsebooleanArray object after app closes

Tags: android, json, performance, gson

I saw several threads on how to save objects in SharedPreferences, in some cases using json and in some other cases using GSON. my question is what is the best method to so that and do you have any good tutorials on how to serialize /deserialize. my main objective is to save the status of checkboxes in my list. the list is very large so the best way to save it was in the SparseBooleanArray.

Thank you for your assistance,

Answer (score 2):

You can get checked positions from SparseBooleanArray. After that you can store it to SharedPreferences or SQLite database.

Comment: The list may contain up to 100 items some of them can be checked while others won't, I can get the positions from the array the question is how to store them in sharedpreferences? As far as I know sharedpreferences are composed from key Value per and that will require a huge amounts of keys, isn't it? I'm searching for a more efficient way, do you have any ideas?

Comment: In that case, save it in SQLite database.

Comment: Thanks, i used Gson eventually, I find it more useful for my app. the sparseBooleanArray is being recreated successfully